# Exclude specific files in a "location" rule

Tags: nginx, webserver, debian

I "secured" my Wordpress installation by making .php-files in /wp-content/ "Not Found"

```
location ~ ^/wp-content/.+\.php$ {
      return 404;
   }
```

How can i exclude specific files/directories in this rule and make them executable again?

Comment: Add another location

Comment: Or use a negative lookahead assertion.